# Multiple Delayed_Job Workers Writing to same table (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job, thinking-sphinx

Is there a way to have multiple delayed_job workers updating to the same table?  I have a Rails 3.09 application using Ruby 1.9.2. I need to run several queries and I want to not have to run them so sequentially since the query results do not rely on each other. However, the results do get written to the same table but not the same row.  Thinking_Sphinx is also involved because it updates the table. Can delayed_job be configured to not lock the full table and allow multiple updates to the same table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with DelayedJob. It's not what's causing table locks. If you're using MyISAM then this is a limitation of your storage engine and you should look at InnoDB instead. If you're on Inno already, you'll need to investigate what's causing the full table lock.